# Can't Drupal be installed on a MySQL server running with default settings?

Tags: mysql, linux, drupal

Meaning root with no password. I get an installation error saying Drupal cannot connect to the database server. I'm using the default XAMPP-packaged MySQL server on Linux. The server is running as I can interact with it through phpMyAdmin.

Warning: PDO::_*construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Invalid argument (trying to connect via unix://) in DatabaseConnection->*_construct() (line 300 of/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/drupal-7_0/includes/database/database.inc).
In order for Drupal to work, and to continue with the installation process, you must resolve all issues reported below. For more help with configuring your database server, see the installation handbook. If you are unsure what any of this means you should probably contact your hosting provider.
Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Invalid argument.
Is the database server running?
Does the database exist, and have you entered the correct database name?
Have you entered the correct username and password?
Have you entered the correct database hostname?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply create a new user per site, that is what I do and really simple to do with phpmyadmin. Just add a new user and then chose "Create database with same name and grant all privileges".

Your error doesn't seem related to not having a password though but about socket vs tcp. Try "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" for the host.

Comment: Berdir is correct. The Drupal 7 install script required me to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 and the installation completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database connection details (DB name, Username, Password, etc). 
Apart from this, make sure HOST NAME is correct and PORT Number also. In my case, port number was different. It was 3307.